# MYSQL Trigger update on a table

Tags: mysql, mariadb, phpmyadmin

Assuming that I have a table, user. How do I calculate the sum of votes and paymentAmt each time they are being updated using trigger? Then, the votes and paymentAmt will be added to the point. I want to do it for every users (1 and 2) everytime the they are updated without selecting the specific user id.May i know how do i automatically update points for each user? My trigger does not update the table even after I alter the datas

```
1) user_ID | votes | paymentAmt | point (USER)
    1          10        20        30 <-- automatically updated
    2          25        30        55
    3          10        40        50
```

## Trigger

```
CREATE Trigger upd_pt 
AFTER UPDATE ON user
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    UPDATE user 
        set point = (select sum(votes) from user) + user.paymentAmt 
        where user.user_ID = new.user_ID;
END
```

Comment: an `UPDATE user` statement will trigger the `UPDATE TRIGGER` on `user` that does an `UPDATE user`.  This  will probably trigger the `UPDATE TRIGGER` on `user` that does an `UPDATE user`.  This  will probably trigger the `UPDATE TRIGGER` on `user` that does an `UPDATE user`.  This  will probably trigger the `UPDATE TRIGGER` on `user` that does an `UPDATE user`.  This  will probably trigger the `UPDATE TRIGGER` on `user` that does an `UPDATE user`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you need:

```
CREATE Trigger upd_pt 
BEFORE UPDATE ON user
FOR EACH ROW 
SET NEW.point = NEW.votes + NEW.paymentAmt
```

This will set `points` before the `user` record is updated, so that total will be stored.

Based on code from the [MySQL 5.7 Reference Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html).

NOTE: For best results, you probably also want to have this as an INSERT trigger, and may want to adjust if `votes` or `paymentAmt` can be `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

If there are tables which are storing votes and PaymentAmount, you need create triggers on those tables to get the aggregated data on User table. If my understanding is wrong, may be you need to provide more details.

Comment: Assuming that i have a single table with two columns (votes and paymentAmt) and each time any of them are updated or total is stored in the point column